# How to scrape multiple tags in single iteration?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a script below that works perfectly - it visits each HREF tag on a list of URLs, then returns the associated p tag information.  It pushes the info directly to a Google Sheet.

I noticed, the player "position" isn't included, because it is an H2 tag not a p... I started to redo the entire script separately to scrape these (2nd script below).

Is there a way I can just re-write the first one to include a column that adds these h2 tags (position)?

**WORKING (RETRIEVES ALL P TAGS)**

```
  import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    import gspread
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
    sh = gc.open_by_key('1DpasSS8yC1UX6WqAbkQ515BwEEjdDL-x74T0eTW8hLM')
    worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(3)
    # AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
    # worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)
    
    
    def get_links(url):
        data = []
        req_url = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")
    
        for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
            a_tag = td.a
            name = a_tag.text
            player_url = a_tag['href']
            print(f"Getting {name}")
    
            req_player_url = requests.get(
                f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
            soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
            div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
            row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}
    
            for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
                try:
                    key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                    row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
                except:     # not all entries have values
                    pass
    
            data.append(row)
    
        return data
    
    
    urls = [
        'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
        'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
        'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
        'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2019',
        'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2018',
    ]
    
    
    res = []
    for url in urls:
        print(f"Getting: {url}")
        data = get_links(url)
        res = [*res, *data]
    
    if res != []:
        header = list(res[0].keys())
        values = [
            header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
        worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED"

)

**NOT WORKING, BUT AN ATTEMPT TO GET POSITIONS:**

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1DpasSS8yC1UX6WqAbkQ515BwEEjdDL-x74T0eTW8hLM')
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(1)
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("h2"):
            try:
                p.get_text(strip=True)
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    # 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    # 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
    # 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2019',
    # 'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2018',
]


res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [
        header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different options:

- Get it with `name` and `url` using `find_next_sibling('td')`

  ```
  pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
  ```
- Get it from the detail page and call it directly

  ```
  row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text
  ```

##### Example

Be aware this example breaks after first iteration for demo purposes, simply remove `break` to get all results

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        ## option#1
        pos = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        ## append option#1 to row
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url, "pos_option1":pos}
        ## option#2
        row['pos_option2'] = div_profile_box.h2.span.text
        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)
        break
    return data

get_links('https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022')
```

##### Output

```
Getting Darius Adams
[{'Name': 'Darius Adams',
  'URL': '/player/Darius-Adams/Summary/28720',
  'pos_option1': 'PG',
  'pos_option2': 'PG',
  'Current Team': 'Fujian',
  'Born': 'Apr 17, 1989(33 years old)',
  'Birthplace/Hometown': 'Decatur, Illinois',
  'Nationality': 'United States',
  'Height': '6-1 (185cm)Weight:165 (75kg)',
  'Current NBA Status': 'Unrestricted Free Agent',
  'Agent': 'Thaddeus Foucher,Joe Smith',
  'Draft Entry': '2011 NBA Draft',
  'Drafted': 'Undrafted',
  'Pre-Draft Team': 'Indianapolis(Sr)',
  'High School': 'MacArthur High School[Decatur, Illinois]'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Hedgehog - I'm a little confused. I'm running the script, but not seeing any results, meaning - in my other script, I have the data printing to a google sheet.. here it seems to just say "getting playername" and printing that to the terminal.  I'm a little confused where you are seeing that output? I'm sorry - new to this trying to learn

Comment: It should appear directly in the terminal, otherwise use `print(get_links('https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022'))` but your goal should be to get one of the two position lines into your script, so you should see the info directly in the sheet